# How to target specific h1 header

Tags: css

I have a specific h1 header I'd like to target with css but not sure how.

Html

```
</div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="content" class="main-container">
<div class="header-callout"></div>
<section class="content-area  pt0 ">
<div id="main" class="container" role="main">
<div class="row">
<div id="primary" class="col-md-8 mb-xs-24 sidebar. 
right">
<article id="post-9949" class="post-9949 page type-page 
status-publish hentry"><header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title">Showcase of the Month</h1>   
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

View [here](https://adsler.co.uk/showcase-of-the-month/)

Basically I'd like to centre it. But `margin: auto` never works.

Comment: `.entry-title { /* ... */ }` (or `h1.entry-title { /* ... */ }`)?

Comment: Thanks. Will that target just that h1 header class?

Comment: yep, unless you assign more elements the _entry-title_ class.

Comment: Thanks. I've got lots of h1 headers. Each page has a h1 header. I'd just like to target that one.....how?

Comment: You could assign this specific one an id as mentioned in another comment below. Here's a link for reference [simple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors#ID_selectors)

Comment: You could have infinity h1 headers and h1.entry-title will not target any of them. UNLESS.... they also have class="entity-title". Okay? Now, if you have more than one <h1 class="entity-title" then you can expect that rule will target exactly those ONLY and not the other h1 headers that do not have the class.

Comment: just do a *little bit*  of reading about CSS classes and IDs, then you'll understand all the comments and answers and know how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
.entry-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

or

```
h1.entry-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

If this is not working, are there other CSS rules that may apply here (like a separate `h1` tag style?) You can make it more specific like this:

```
header > h1.entry-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

Here, the `>` means h1 tags that are immediate children of a header tag and have class entry-title.

---

If you only want to target this specific `h1` tag, give it an ID:

```
<h1 class="entry-title" id="my-title">Text</h1>
```

IDs can be targeted using #:

```
#my-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

or

```
h1#my-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

You can even ensure you select only those that have a certain class and a certain ID with this:

```
h1#my-title.entry-title {
    /* Your CSS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will that target just that h1 header class and not other h1 headers?

Comment: `h1.entry-title` targets all h1 elements with the entry-title class. If there is only one, that is all it will target.

Comment: But I have lots of h1 headers and it's only this particular one I'd like to target....

Comment: Do the other h1 headers have the _entry-title_ class as well?

Comment: Perhaps consider using an ID instead. Those are meant for unique elements. Aside, it's okay if you have many h1 headers, but how many of them actually use the class `entry-title` ? If there's only one, then you will not target the others.

Comment: Yes, as ThisClark says, an ID might be more useful - I will update.

Comment: @Thisclark basically I'd like to center it in mobile and desktop using @media but `margin:auto` never works.

Comment: @Chris. basically I'd like to center it in mobile and desktop using media query but margin:auto never works. –

Comment: @user11963881 You can use `text-align: center;` inside your media query. This will work for inline elements like `<h*>` and `<p>`.